# How to create batches for batch processing in python?

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra, batch-processing

I have a data stored in **cassandra** which I want to retrieve in python for batch processing.
I want to create batches based on **time** column. Say I extracted the data from cassandra between **9:00:00** and **10:00:00**. Now I wanted to create batches for per minute data. (Same timestamp can be in many rows).

```
1st batch is of 9:00:00 data.
2nd batch is of 9:00:01 data.
```

These batches will be feed to other modules to process one after another.

My code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster 

cluster_cont=['127.0.0.1']
keyspace='demo'
query='Select * from demo.table1'
cond1='9:00:00'
cond2='10:00:00'

def readD(cluster_cont, keyspace, query, cond1, cond2):

    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=cluster_cont)
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

    session.default_fetch_size = None

    rslt = pd.DataFrame(session.execute(query+" where time>="+cond1" and time<="+cond2, timeout=None))
    df = rslt._current_rows

return df
```

In above code I want to iterate between cond1 to cond2 to create batches of  dataframe. How can I achieve that?

I tried to convert **cond1** and **cond2** into datetime object but it gives an error.

```
df=readD(cluster_cont, keyspace, query, cond1, cond2)
cond1=datetime.datetime.strptime(cond1,'%H:%M:%S').time()
cond2=datetime.datetime.strptime(cond2,'%H:%M:%S').time()

while cond1 <= cond2 :
   cond1 = cond1 + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
   df=df[df['time']==cond1]
```

Traceback

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Even if I manage to iterate over the time how can I feed these data frames to other modules one by one? Should I change my approach?

Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks.

P.S:  I am using python-cassandra driver to extract data.

Comment: Data retrieval patterns in Cassandra heavily dependent on the table structure. Please update your post with table's definition